# display products in front page of specific category

Tags: product, category

I have a homepage.phtml which will create a block by calling a new.phtml

homepage.phtml

```
<div class="home-page-new-product">
    <p class="new-product-title"><?php echo $this->__('New Product') ?></p>
    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("catalog/product_new")->setTemplate("catalog/product/new.phtml")->toHtml() ?>
</div>
```

first line of new.phtml

```
<?php if (($_products = $this->getProductCollection()) && $_products->getSize()): ?>
..
```

The question is how can I display products of specific category, is it possible to simply adjust the code of new.phtml only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The block type `catalog/product_new` does not allow you to specify a category id. You could try using the `catalog/product_list` block instead which does allow setting a category id.

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("catalog/product_list")->setTemplate("catalog/product/list.phtml")->setCategoryId('category_id')->toHtml();
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for something like this:
In CMS Pages > Home Page, add this code:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_new" column_count="4" category_id="5" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_homepage" template="catalog/product/new.phtml"}}
```